# Bootstrap Accordion Tabs Not Collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap accordion and I only need one tab to be opened at a time. What is interesting is that whenever there are two tabs next to each other, one of them doesn't close. This does not happen if, for example, the first one is already opened and you try to then open the third one. Why is this happening?

URL: http://fer.bitballoon.com/faq

```
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true"><!-- begin accordion -->
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Collapsible Group Item #2
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- end accordion -->
```

Comment: Posted this as a comment because it is a link.  Will be helpful for anyone that runs into the same issue.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `#` (`id` identifier) on your second tab

`data-parent="accordion"` should be `data-parent="#accordion"`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you, this solved the issue!